# checkbox issues, can't get array to stay CHECKED on form submit

Tags: php, checkbox

I've been trying to solve this problem for the last 3 hours and I'm getting close, but my inexperience is showing. I've tried all the permutations I can think of.

I have a form with checkboxes. The values are retrieved from mysql. The form is being submitted to the same page. [You can view it live here](http://www.renewabled.com/locator/index.php). Type "Axminster" for the search.

The original checkbox code is as follows:

```
<?php
$categories_list = split('[
]', get_setting('categories', $db));
foreach ($categories_list AS $cat)
{
$cat = trim($cat);
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\"  name=\"categories[]\" value=\"" . $cat . "\">" . $cat .     "<br>";
}
?>
```

so I then submit the form and as normal I want the checkbox checked values to remain checked. For a dropdown box in my form I have used the code

```
<?php if($radius == $_POST['radius']) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>
```

and this works perfectly, however I'm trying to use the following code to get the checked checkboxes to remain checked, and I'm having no luck:

```
<?php

$categories_list = split('[
]', get_setting('categories', $db));
foreach ($categories_list AS $cat)
{

$cat = trim($cat);
// I've added these two lines, and added " . $select . " to the input field.
foreach ($_POST['categories'] AS $category) {
if($cat == $category) { $select = "CHECKED"; } }
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" " . $select . " name=\"categories[]\" value=\"" . $cat . "\">" . $cat . "<br>";
} 
?>
```

The result is that every checkbox after the first checked checkbox is also being checked. For example I have four checkboxes and even if I check only the 2nd checkbox, the 3rd and 4th are also being checked on the next page.

I'm completely lost now. Please can anyone help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what your actual question is.  Could you elaborate more on the expected behavior versus the received behavior?

Comment: as it describes, I'm trying to post a form and for the checkbox values to be remembered on next page. however, it's not working out as more checkboxes are being checked than were checked.

Comment: lol... I thought I read your question wrong and deleted my solution :p
anyways, you should always re-initialize variables you use within loops or they'll carry over their values to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
if(isset($_POST['categories']) && in_array($cat, $_POST['categories']))
```

You also need to reset the `$select` on each loop, or use an `else{}`, as once it is set using your `foreach`, the value never changes, so all checkboxes after the selected will be checked as well.

the code could now look like-

```
<?php

$categories_list = split('[
]', get_setting('categories', $db));
foreach ($categories_list AS $cat)
{

$cat = trim($cat);
// I've added these two lines, and added " . $select . " to the input field.
if(isset($_POST['categories']) && in_array($cat, $_POST['categories'])) { $select = "CHECKED"; } 
else { $select = ''; }
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" " . $select . " name=\"categories[]\" value=\"" . $cat . "\">" . $cat . "<br>";
} 
?>
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you very much Sean. What a talent !